# Why does Mathematica not give the simple solution of the given equations?

Tags: equation-solving, functions, trigonometry

I want to solve this system of two equations for $x$
$$\{  \sin (2\pi x)+\sin (\frac{2\pi}y)=0   \quad ,  \quad \cos (2\pi x)-\cos (\frac{2\pi}y)=0   \}   \qquad (1)$$

I use `Solve`:

```
Solve[  {  Sin[ 2 π  x] + Sin[(2 π )/y ] == 0, Cos[ 2 π  x] - Cos[(2 π )/y ] == 0  }, x ] // Simplify

(*{{x -> ConditionalExpression[ArcTan[Cos[(2 π )/y], -Sin[(2 π )/y]]/(2 π ) + C[1], C[1] \[Element] Integers]}}*)
```

The result is in the form of a *conditional expression*:

$$x=\frac{1}{2\pi}\text{ArcTan}[\cos (\frac{2\pi}y),-\sin (\frac{2\pi}y)]+c_1, \qquad c_1\in\mathbb{Z}$$

Substituting $x=\dfrac{1}{2\pi}\arctan\left(\frac{-\sin (\frac{2\pi}y)}{\cos (\frac{2\pi}y)}\right)+m$ into $(1)$, I get

```
Sin[ 2 π  x] + Sin[(2 π )/y] /. x -> ((ArcTan[-(Sin[(2 π )/y]/Cos[(2 π )/y])]/(2 π )) + m) // FullSimplify[#,  Assumptions ->  y > 0 && y \[Element] Reals && m \[Element] Integers] &
Cos[ 2 π  x] - Cos[(2 π )/y] /. x -> ((ArcTan[-(Sin[(2 π )/y]/Cos[(2 π )/y])]/(2 π )) +  m) // FullSimplify[#,  Assumptions ->  y > 0 && y \[Element] Reals && m \[Element] Integers] &

(* (-1 + Sign[Sec[(2 π )/y]]) Sin[(2 π )/y]*)
(* (-1 + Sign[Sec[(2 π )/y]]) Cos[(2 π )/y] *)
```

which means that the equations vanish simultaneously if $\text{sgn} (\frac{2\pi}y)=+1$, i.e., only for those $y$ for which $\text{sgn} (\frac{2\pi}y)=+1$, we can simplify $x=\dfrac{1}{2\pi}\arctan\left(\frac{-\sin (\frac{2\pi}y)}{\cos (\frac{2\pi}y)}\right)+m$ as $x=m-\frac1y$

> On the other hand, it is evident that both equations $(1)$ vanish at $x=m-\frac1y$ for all values of $y$ (while some of them may not satisfy $\text{sgn} (\frac{2\pi}y)=+1$).

```
 Sin[ 2 π x] + Sin[(2 π)/y] /. x -> m - 1/y //  FullSimplify[#, Assumptions ->  y > 0 && y \[Element] Reals && m \[Element] Integers] &

Cos[ 2 π x] - Cos[(2 π)/y] /. x -> m - 1/y // FullSimplify[#,  Assumptions ->  y > 0 && y \[Element] Reals && m \[Element] Integers] &

(*0*)
(*0*)
```

Comment: `ArcTan[x, y]` is the same as $\arctan(y/x)$. I think you have it switched when you plugged the thing back in.

Comment: Indeed, when I just copy and past the result out of the `ConditionalExpression`, changing `C[1]` to `m` in your second code block, I get zero.

Comment: @march I have used the same expression as you mentioned $\arctan(y/x)$.

Comment: Note that if you run `Simplify[expr, y > 2 \[Pi]]` on the conditional expression, it gives you `m - 1/y`.

Comment: @march Yes, for $y>4$, the conditional solution is the same as $x=m-\frac1y$. But my question is that while both equations vanish for $x=m-\frac1y$ for all values of $y$, the conditional solution of Mathematica only works for $y>4$? Which one should I trust?

Comment: I'm sorry, you're right.  *I* switched them. I suspect the issue is that `ArcTan[x, y]` is not *exactly* the same as $\arctan(y/x)$, because one has to take into account which quadrant the `x` and `y` are.  See the documentation for `ArcTan`.  This is why directly plugging in the expression you get from `Solve` yields 0 whereas plugging in `ArcTan[y/x]` gives something different.

Comment: I suggest plotting the result `ArcTan[Cos[(2 \[Pi])/y], -Sin[(2 \[Pi])/y]]/(2 \[Pi])` between, say 0.25 and 6, then between 0.1 and 6, to get an idea of what it does.  The problem is that the function has an infinite number of discontinuities as you approach $y=0$. On each continuous section of the function, it's equal to $m-1/y$ for some $m$, but the problem is that *Mathematica* can't seem to generate a closed form for the set of discontinuities, and so it just returns `m - 1/y` once it's sure there will be no more discontinuities (which is actually for `y>2`).

Comment: This system this system of equations is quite simple to solve analytically without using a computer, why not ask on the mathematics part of stack exchange?

Comment: @Joe I have written in the question that it is evident that this equation has an analytic solution, I wanted to ask why Mathematica does not give this simple solution! So, it was related to Mathematica Stackexchange!

Answer (score 14, accepted):

I think your assumption is that $y\in \mathbb{R}$ is real, so you can put it as the condition (otherwise it is assumed to be complex):

```
SolveValues[
Sin[2π x]+Sin[2π/y]==0&&
Cos[2π x]-Cos[2π/y]==0&&
y∈Reals
,x]//FullSimplify
```

So after `FullSimplify` you get 2 answers that you are looking for:

$\begin{array}{l}
 \fbox{$-\frac{1}{y}+2 c_1\text{ if }y\in \mathbb{R}\land c_1\in \mathbb{Z}$} \\
 \fbox{$-\frac{1}{y}+1+2 c_1\text{ if }y\in \mathbb{R}\land c_1\in \mathbb{Z}$} \\
\end{array}$

If you are looking for a similar compact answer in the complex domain then this should do:

```
SolveValues[
Sin[2π x]+Sin[2π/y]==0&&
Cos[2π x]-Cos[2π/y]==0
,x]//FullSimplify
```

$\fbox{$c_1-\frac{i \log \left(e^{-\frac{2 i \pi }{y}}\right)}{2 \pi }\text{ if }c_1\in
   \mathbb{Z}$}$

Answer (score 9):

The reason that the second code snippet in the OP doesn't evaluate to zero is because `ArcTan[x, y]` is not the same as `ArcTan[y/x]` for every choice of `x` and `y`.  This is explained in the documentation for `ArcTan`: it matters which quadrant the points $(x,y)$ is in. To see this, notice:

```
Plot[{
   ArcTan[Cos[(2 π)/y], -Sin[(2 π)/y]]/(2 π),
   ArcTan[-Sin[(2 π)/y]/Cos[(2 π)/y]]/(2 π)},
 {y, 1, 6}, 
 PlotRange -> {{0, 6}, All}, PlotPoints -> 100]
```

results in

[image]

Indeed, if we plug the solution that `Solve` actually spits out, we get zero:

```
FullSimplify[
  Sin[2 π x] + Sin[(2 π)/y] /. x -> ArcTan[Cos[(2 π)/y], -Sin[(2 π)/y]]/(2 π) + m,
  m ∈ Integers]
(* 0 *)
```

---

The second issue in the OP is that *Mathematica* doesn't simplify to the simple solution `m - 1/y`, which *is* a solution (with caveats), which we can see from

```
Simplify[ArcTan[Cos[(2 π)/y], -Sin[(2 π)/y]]/(2 π) + m, {y > 4}]
```

However, the issue is that the function actually has an infinite number discontinuities as we approach $y=0$. On each continuous piece of the function, it is equal to `m - 1/y` for some integer `m`, but it seems like *Mathematica* is unable to come up with a general expression for the location of the discontinuities, and hence it doesn't simplify the expression to `m - 1/y` until it's sure that there will be no discontinuities.

To see this, consider the plot:

```
Plot[ArcTan[Cos[(2 π)/y], -Sin[(2 π)/y]]/(2 π), {y, 0.2, 6}, PlotRange -> {{0, 6}, All}, PlotPoints -> 300]
```

[image]

Now, interestingly enough, we can paste the solutions that *Mathematica* spits out together (i.e., the set of solutions for every `m`), and it turns out that it maps out the set of curves `m - 1/y`!

```
GraphicsRow[{
  Plot[Table[ArcTan[Cos[(2 π)/y], -Sin[(2 π)/y]]/(2 π) + m, {m, -5, 5}] // Evaluate, {y, 0.2, 6}, PlotRange -> {{0, 6}, {-6, 6}}],
  Plot[Table[m - 1/y, {m, -5, 5}] // Evaluate, {y, 0.2, 6}, PlotRange -> {{0, 6}, {-6, 6}}]
  }]
```

[image]

I suspect that because *Mathematica* tries to find general solutions first, it writes things in terms of `ArcTan[x, y]`, and once it's there, it gets stuck, because it needs to care about an infinite number of discontinuities, and it's hard for a computer algebra system to dealt with and recognize that `m - 1/y` is a general solution to the problem.

---

Finally, note that *Mathematica* does at least know that this family of curves solves the original set of equations:

```
Sin[2 π x] + Sin[(2 π)/y] /. x -> m - 1/y /. Sin[a_] :> Sin@Expand@a // TrigExpand // Simplify
Cos[2 π x] - Cos[(2 π)/y] /. x -> m - 1/y /. Cos[a_] :> Cos@Expand@a // TrigExpand // Simplify
(* 2 Cos[π (m - 2/y)] Sin[m π] *)
(* -2 Sin[m π] Sin[π (m - 2/y)] *)
```

From which we can see that both of these are clearly zero when `m` is an integer.

Comment: Thank you for the answer.

Comment: @sara96. Yeah, sorry for the mix-up! The problem was more interesting than I expected on a first viewing.